# Microsoft's solution for deploying visual studio project types other than websites

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, webdeploy

I know within Visual Studio I can publish my website project to an IIS website using Web Deploy. I've also been looking at Visual Studio Team Services which has release templates for IIS Website Deployments but that also looks like it's using Web Deploy behind the scenes. However, I need to deploy regular exe's and windows services to application servers, what is the Microsoft solution for doing this?

Comment: Why do you want to deploy exe to IIS website? Of cause, you can deliver the exe to the physical path of IIS website, but it can't be shown when you browsing in the website.

Comment: I don't want to deploy exe's to a website. I want to be able to deploy(release) exe's or windows services to application servers. I've previously used Jenkins with Ant to do this, but I'm looking for a pure Microsoft solution for my current project.

Comment: What's the OS on your application server? Windows or Linux?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT  Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Windows Machine File Copy](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy) task to copy the build output to your application server and use [PowerShell on Target Machines](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines) task to configure the application if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are pushing something directly to a web server or cloud, there isn't much else that VS can push automatically.

You could push exe's to a web server, or to a file storage service by packaging them into something. However, if you are saying, you want to push out exe's directly from a VS solution (as in exe generated by a VS solution), I don't think that would work.